# VB.Net Text Visibility

Tags: vb.net

I want to change some text's visibility but my code can't do it. I don't get any errors. My code is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Property Ay1TarihLabel As Object

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SatisDataSet.SatisT' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SatisTTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SatisDataSet.SatisT)

        Ay1TarihLabel.Visible = False

    End Sub

End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set a breakpoint a `Me.SatisTTableAdapter.Fill` and see if you really get to `Ay1TarihLabel.Visible = False`. If not, execute the `Fill` in the debugger's quick-watch window. Then inspect the returned rows of `Me.SatisDataSet.SatisT.GetErrors()`. Every row has a `RowError` property which leads you to the problem.

Comment: Or if the form is not yet visible that line of code will do nothing. You could set it at design time or do it in another form event, this might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the replies. When I set breakpoint I'm getting Ay1TarihLabel Nothing Object. I don't know how to use GetErrors()

Comment: @nikel: You are declaring `Ay1TarihLabel` as `Object` but where do you initialize it? Why do you declare it manually at all?

Comment: Tony, I'm trying to change the text's visibility when it hasn't loaded yet, as I understand. But when I put a button I'm getting error. Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: @Tim: because otherwise I'm getting error: Error 1 'Ay1TarihLabel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. C:\Users\Nikel\Desktop\Satis\Form1.vb 64 9 Satis

Comment: @nikel: why don't you add the label with the correct `Name` in the designer? Then it will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should call .visible = false against a real label, if you did this in designer mode you'd be looking for:
    `Friend WithEvents Ay1TarihLabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label`
or something like that.  That you can set visible = false on load.

Comment: Yes, I did it in designer mode. I'm new to VB.Net Where will I put Friend WithEvents Ay1TarihLabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label

Comment: Just replace the Private Property Line with it, but if you did this in designer mode it should be in code already, search your solution for Ay1TarihLabel